# Triggering an event in C#/Unity with a bool value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just delving into the event systems in Unity and I'm trying to understand how I might set up an event listener that listens for whether a bool is true or false. I want to use it to basically start of stop player movement along a spline. I've been following along with tutorials and "totally understand" until I don't and then I get completely lost. :/ I need help. Here's where I am so far. I have a GameController script and I've created an event action:

```
public event Action OnRaceStartBool;
public void RaceStart()
{
     OnRaceStartBool?.Invoke();
}
```

then I've defined the actions in another script like this:

```
void Start() {
     GameController.Instance.OnRaceStartBool += OnRaceStart;
     GameController.Instance.OnRaceStartBool -= OnRaceEnd;
}

private void OnRaceStart() {
     StartCoroutine(PlayerSpeed());
}

private void OnRaceEnd() {
     StopCoroutine(PlayerSpeed());
     Player1Speed = 0;
     Player2Speed = 0;
}

public IEnumerator PlayerSpeed() {
     while (GetComponent<GameController>().raceStarted) {
          Player1Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player1Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;
          Player2Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player2Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;

          yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
      }
}
```

I'm not sure if I have things correct so far, but what I am missing is how to create the bool trigger that calls the function to either start or stop the couroutine. I basically just want to test it out as a bool that I can see in the unity inspector. What and where do I need to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can accomplish what you want.
I use this for testing various methods from time to time.

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool doSomeAction;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (doSomeAction)
        {
            doSomeAction = false;
            DoSomeAction();
        }
    }
    private void DoSomeAction()
    {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

Not applicable to your question (since you use events), but this works in the editor as well if you mark the class with `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute.  Handy for doing simple editor stuff without needing an editor or window.

Comment: I was trying to use events to avoid an update function from constantly running

Comment: I thought you wanted to test the events using a bool.  This is for testing, not for production.  `"I basically just want to test it out as a bool that I can see in the unity inspector."`

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
 GameController.Instance.OnRaceStartBool += OnRaceStart;
 GameController.Instance.OnRaceStartBool -= OnRaceEnd;
```

is not doing what you expect!

- You are **adding** the `OnRaceStart` as a listener
- You are **removing** the `OnRaceEnd` → this on is never ever going to be called at all!

---

> I basically just want to test it out as a bool that I can see in the unity inspector.

I would discourage from doing so. There won't be a lot of ways (without either a custom Inspector or polling) to have a flag exposed in the Inspector and at the same time invoke events based on it.

Even less it should be stored as a flag in your listening class but rather only handled by the `GameController` (single source of truth).

---

You probably rather want to use a parameterized

```
public event Action<bool> OnRaceState;

public void RaceStart()
{
     OnRaceStartBool?.Invoke(true);
}

public void RaceEnd()
{
     OnRaceStartBool?.Invoke(false);
}
```

and then handle it accordingly

```
private Coroutine racingRoutine;

void Start() 
{
    GameController.Instance.OnRaceState += OnRaceStateChanged;
}

private void OnRaceStateChanged(bool isRacing)
{
     if(!isRacing)
     {
         if(racingRoutine != null) 
         {
             StopCoroutine(racingRoutine);
             racingRoutine = null;
         }

         Player1Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = 0;
         Player2Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = 0;
     } 
     else 
     {
         racingRoutine = StartCoroutine(PlayerSpeed());
     }
}

public IEnumerator PlayerSpeed()
{
     while (true) 
     {
          Player1Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player1Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;
          Player2Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player2Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;


          yield return new WaitForeconds(0.1f);
      }
}
```

---

Note though that the argument `I was trying to use events to avoid an update function from constantly running` is a bit vague.

Basically you have one (the Coroutine) running and polling values each frame (or at least each 0.1 seconds) anyway. This basically **is** like a temporary little `Update` method that gets called `IEnumerator.MoveNext` each frame.

You might rather want to make the entire float values event driven and only adjust their value once it is supposed to change.